# Low virtual memory on Sony Ericsson Xperia

Tags: android

My application contains lot of images loading at runtime. This app works fine in almost all android devices but in Xperia it oftenly crashes with low virtual memory.
plz help me...

Answer (score 1):

you need to catch the low memroy error and reduces the size of downloaded image as below.

```
 catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("Out of memory error", e.toString());
             reduce_size();
         }
.....

BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    int width_tmp=options.outWidth, height_tmp=options.outHeight;
    int scale=1;
    while(true){
        if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp/=2;
        height_tmp/=2;
        scale*=2;
    }

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    Bitmap btm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
    img_t.setImageBitmap(btm);
```

Comment: all the images are taken from the drawable

Comment: but i cant resize the images they all are in a fixed size.

Comment: you need to check where your are getting out of memory exception , while downloading or while showing images in imageview?

Comment: There is a next button in this activity on clicking on this button the screen get loaded with new images. Each times there will be upto 11 images loaded in the screen.

Comment: I think downloading of images doesn't result into out of memory, so output inputstream should be handled in the same way as specify in my answer . When your downloading of particular image done then inputstream should be decoded as BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options); and rest is same as in answer